# Efficient ways to count number of items in a sorted array for many different start/end values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to count number of S&P open days between a start and an end date, for many different start/end dates.

A fake example

```
SPopen = pd.bdate_range(start = '1950-01-01', end = '2020-01-01')
startdates = pd.bdate_range(start = '1970-01-01', end = '2000-01-01')
enddates = startdates + pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')
```

For each pair in start/end dates, I can do

```
np.sum( (SPopen > start) & (SPopen <= end) )
```

to get the number of SP open days, but looping several thousand times is slow. Is there an efficient way to do this?

NB: SP doesn't open on all week days and `np.busday_count` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Introduction

Very interesting problem and could be really useful when dealing with datetimes of dataframes or just any problem that involves counting of elements that satisfy the interval limits.

### Proposed approach

To solve it, we can *abuse* the fact that the data is sorted and the intervals as well, by using [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) with its optional `'left'` and `'right'` arguments. I started off with a NumPy sample in mind and this generalizes well enough for datetimes as well.

**Steps involved**

Let me playback my history into solving this problem :

1] Given inputs -

```
In [618]: a  # Data array
Out[618]: array([ 0,  2,  4, 14, 15, 27, 29])

In [619]: s0  # Interval start
Out[619]: array([ 2,  6,  9, 15, 25])

In [620]: s1  # Interval stop
Out[620]: array([ 7, 10, 11, 19, 29])
```

2] Get the left, right index positions -

```
In [621]: search_stop = np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right')
     ...: search_start = np.searchsorted(a,s0,'left')
     ...:
```

3] Get the differentaion for the usual cases -

```
In [622]: out = search_stop - search_start
```

4] For cases when the start positions are already present in a, `np.searchsorted(a,s0,'left')` would have given us a lesser index, so offset for it -

```
In [623]: out -= a[search_start] == s0
```

5] For cases, when no elements were caught by the intervals, we might have negative counts because of the last step offseting. So, clip these at zeros and thus we have the desired output -

```
In [624]: out.clip(min=0)
Out[624]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 2])
```

Additionally, for intervals that start outside of any element in the data array, `search_start` would be outside of array length, so use a mask to limit these computations.

Summing up everything, we would end up with an implementation like so -

```
def vectorized_interval_count(a, s0, s1):
    search_stop = np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right')
    search_start = np.searchsorted(a,s0,'left')

    L = np.searchsorted(search_start, a.size)
    out = search_stop - search_start 
    out[:L] -= (a[search_start[:L]] == s0[:L])
    out.clip(min=0, out = out)
    return out
```

**Massive improvement**

As it turns out, as mentioned in the [`comments by OP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653830/efficient-ways-to-count-number-of-items-in-a-sorted-array-for-many-different-sta/41655255?noredirect=1#comment70510614_41655255), we can simply look for `'right'` indices and the respective differentiations would functionally mean the count of elements in those `left-open` and `right-closed` intervals .

Thus, a one-liner solution would be -

```
np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right') - np.searchsorted(a,s0,'right')
```

### Runtime test

Testing it out on the given huge sample dataset in the question, I got -

```
In [795]: SPopen = pd.bdate_range(start = '1950-01-01', end = '2020-01-01')
     ...: startdates = pd.bdate_range(start = '1970-01-01', end = '2000-01-01')
     ...: enddates = startdates + pd.Timedelta(1, 'Y')
     ...: 

In [796]: a = SPopen
     ...: s0 = startdates
     ...: s1 = enddates
     ...: 

In [797]: out1 = [np.sum( (a > s0[i]) & (a <= s1[i]) ) for i in range(len(s0))]
     ...: out2 = vectorized_interval_count(a, s0, s1)
     ...: out3 = np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right') - np.searchsorted(a,s0,'right')
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out2)
     ...: print np.allclose(out1, out3)
     ...: 
True
True

In [798]: %timeit [np.sum( (a > s0[i]) & (a <= s1[i]) ) for i in range(len(s0))]
1 loops, best of 3: 4.44 s per loop

In [799]: %timeit vectorized_interval_count(a, s0, s1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 842 µs per loop

In [800]: %timeit np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right') - np.searchsorted(a,s0,'right')
1000 loops, best of 3: 559 µs per loop
```

Thus, seeing close to **`8,000x`** speedup there over a loop-comprehension! (Thanks to OP!)

Comment: `searchsorted` is the way to go! For my left open right closed count, using both `right`, ie `np.searchsorted(a,s1,'right') - np.searchsorted(a,s0,'right')` would do the job, right?

Comment: @jf328 Awesome, great improvement! Thanks. Yes, that works just as well! Added into the post. Hope that's okay with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `startdates` and `enddates` into a DataFrame then you can use the `apply` method to iteratively compute what you need.

```
SPopen = pd.bdate_range(start = '1950-01-01', end = '2020-01-01')
df = pd.DataFrame({'start':startdates, 'end':enddates})
df.apply(lambda x: ((SPopen > x.start) & (SPopen <= x.end)).sum(), axis=1)
```

Which returns the following first rows. It takes 3 seconds on my machine

```
0       261
1       260
2       261
3       261
4       261
5       261
6       260
```